# Expected area of rectangle

Tags: statistics

This question is taken from Rice - Mathematical statistics.

A random rectangle is formed in the following way: The base, X, is chosen
to be a uniform [0, 1] random variable and after having generated the base,
the height is chosen to be uniform on [0, X]. Use the law of total expectation,
Theorem A of Section 4.4.1, to find the expected circumference and area of the
rectangle.

I have trouble understanding the answer for finding the expected area of rectangle.

Let H be the height of the rectangle. The area is XH, so

$E(XH) = E(E(XH|X)) = E(XE(H|X)) = 1/2 E(X^2)$

Can someone kindly explain how do you derive the 3rd part from the 2nd part of the equation ?

Comment: It's a basic property of conditional expectation. Haven't you encountered that in the book yet?

Comment: No. which property are you referring to?

Comment: You may check this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Basic_properties). "_If $X$ is $\mathcal{H}$-measurable, then $E(XY\mid\mathcal{H})=XE(Y\mid\mathcal{H})$._"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what $E(XH|X)$ means? It is expected value of $XH$ **if we know $X$**. So X is a constant, and $E(cH)=cE(H)$ - this is a common property of expectation.